# jQuery selectors - Skipping certain input

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have the following function for clearing input forms:

```
function clearForm(form) {
  $(':input', form).each(function() {
    var type = this.type;
    var tag = this.tagName.toLowerCase();

    if (type == 'text' || type == 'password' || tag == 'textarea')
      this.value = "";
    else if (type == 'checkbox' || type == 'radio')
      this.checked = false;
    else if (tag == 'select')
      this.selectedIndex = -1;
  });
};
```

Is there any way I can stop it from clearing inputs which are 'hidden'?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, instead of

```
$(':input', form)
```

Use

```
$(':input:visible', form)
```

Answer (score 0):

`$(':input:visible', form).each(...`

Answer (score 0):

```
$(':input:visible').val([])
```

You don't need any of the code in the each function, the single line above will do it.